# How to do both things together: adjust subplot spacings and place the legend outside of the plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have 9 matplotlib subplots arranged in a grid. I'm trying to do two simple things: (1) adjust subplot spacing to reduce white space, (2) place the legend outside of the plot. Individually, both things are super easy. Together, they don't work: If I place legend outside of the subplots using bbox_to_achnor=(...), subplot spacing gets messed up and subplots_adjust(...) don't work anymore.

UPD: This works for tight spacing:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(3, 3)

plt.subplot(331)
# plot something on every subplot
plt.subplot(339)
# plot something here too

plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0, hspace=0)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.savefig("blabla.pdf", format="pdf")
```

And with this code all figures become squeezed:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(3, 3)

plt.subplot(331)
# plot something on every subplot
plt.subplot(339)
# plot something here too

# add outside legend to the first plot
plt.subplot(331)
lgd = plt.legend(ncol=1, loc=2, prop={'size': 10}, bbox_to_anchor=4.2, 0.2))

plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0, hspace=0)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.savefig("blabla.pdf", format="pdf", bbox_inches="tight", bbox_extra_artists=(lgd,))
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Things will supposedly work fine if you use the legend with the figure object `fig`. Currently you use it with the last `plt` object which correspond to the last subfigure `339`. Using `fig`, you don't need a large offset of `4.2` for the `bbox_to_anchor`. Something like 1.1 or 1.2 should work fine

```
lgd = fig.legend(ncol=1, loc=2, prop={'size': 10}, bbox_to_anchor=(1.2, 0.2))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the advice! The trick worked for me. I'm having hard time to understand why this "squeeze" effect occur though.